# X.ToCharArray().Length EQUALS GetBytes(X).Length

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

```
string s = "test";
int charCount = s.ToCharArray().Length;
int byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s).Length;
```

When can (charCount != byteCount) happen? I believe in case of Unicode characters but not in general case.

.NET supports Unicode characters but is that the default(System.Text.Encoding.Default) encoding for .NET? "System.Text.Encoding.Default" shows "System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding" as the encoding which is single byte.

Comment: Internally, all .NET strings are stored UTF-16. This is separate from the `System.Text.Encoding.Default` encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default encoding is UTF8 which can contain 1-4 bytes of space per character.

charCount and byteCount will not be equal when any character in string s uses more than 1 byte.

To force the use of 4 bytes you can check using the Unicode encoding, then byteCount will = 8.

```
int byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s).Length;
```

Comment: Ok. So the type of encoding force packing of characters. For Unicode, each char has to take 2 bytes, ASCII will always fit char in 1 byte and UTF-8 can either take 1 or 2 bytes depending on the char.

Comment: @A9S6: When you say "Unicode", you really mean "UTF-16" (that is what `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` implements).  It is important to make that distinction, because "Unicode" is not an encoding.  UTF-8 and UTF-16 are encodings for Unicode.  In any case, UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 bytes per Unicode character, depending on whether surrogates are used.  And UTF-8 uses 1-4 bytes like James said, not 1-2 bytes.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: char.MaxValue gives 65536 i.e. 2 bytes long. If UTF-XX can take upto 4 bytes then how is it going to fit, or is there something I am missing? Now I can relate UTF-XX with the number of bytes it requires, I think the XX is the minimum number of bytes it will take.

Comment: A `char` is indeed 2 bytes in size, so a single `char` can only hold a value up to 65535. However, to access Unicode codepoints above 65535, UTF-16 defines surrogates, which use *2* `char` values, a high surrogate and a low surrogate. All of the UTF-XX encodings other than UTF-32 are variable-length encodings, where XX denotes how many bits are used for each codeunit in the string (UTF-7 is 7-bit, UTF-8 is 8-bit, UTF-16 is 16-bit, and UTF-32 is 32-bit). Each encoding, other than UTF-32, can use multiple codeunits to represent a single Unicode codepoint.

Comment: ... and all of the UTF-XX encodings support the full 21 bit codepoints that Unicode current defines.

Answer (score 1):

The character count will be different from the byte count whenever you use an encoding that uses more than one byte per character. This is the case for several encodings, including UTF-16 (the internal representation of .NET strings) and UTF-32.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `char` stores more than just a single byte in .NET, though

Comment: @Cameron: (charCount == byteCount) on my system. Can you prove char takes more than one byte? I thought the following will make the two variables differ but no: string s = char.ConvertFromUtf32(400);

Comment: @A9S6: See [char.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.maxvalue.aspx) ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: I think the size is 16 bits to support both single and multibyte characters (ASCII, Unicode).

Comment: @A9S6: Exactly. So the byte count could quite easily differ from the character count. Please see [this code sample I wrote](http://ideone.com/uKEKf)