# string.Length vs string.ToCharArray().Length

Tags: c#, string

I'm cleaning up some old code that's repeatedly doing `myString.ToCharArray().Length`; instead of `myString.Length`.

Before I refactor `ToCharArray()` out, are there any circumstances where doing so would result in different behavior?

Comment: I think it's hard to imagine every possible scenario.  I think it's one of those things where you'll have to test and see.

Comment: @user1477388 I've already looked at trivial cases.  If there was going to be an exception it would be in the real of 'interesting' unicode behavior; and not normal everyday cases.  Iterating over the entire charset to brute force a few billion test strings would take much longer than asking the question.

Comment: @DanNeely See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495523/x-tochararray-length-equals-getbytesx-length

Comment: @voo since I'm not dumping to bytes anywhere that doesn't appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference : have a look the method code with reflector : it will allocate a char[] based on the length of the string.

Comment: Specifically, both the original string and the `char[]` returned by `ToCharArray()` will be a UTF-16 representation of the string contents. The length in both cases is the number of UTF-16 code points required to represent the text, so it will match.

Comment: The second can have NullReferenceExceptions too

Comment: What does the `NullReferenceException` note have to do with anything? This would happen in both cases were the string `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Both will definitely return the same length, representing the number of characters (`char`s). There'll be one char per each index of the string (or array), and, then, the following [could be worthy of mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.length.aspx):

> The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this
>   instance, not the number of Unicode characters. The reason is that a
>   Unicode character might be represented by more than one Char. Use the
>   System.Globalization.StringInfo class to work with each Unicode
>   character instead of each Char.

From this you can also deduce that `ToCharArray`, given that it is ["A Unicode character array whose elements are the individual characters of this instance"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ezftk57x.aspx), that they behave the same.

I'm not sure what the not on `NullReferenceException` is about, as both are susceptible to that, too.

Answer (score 2):

> result in different behavior?

*Well*, as others said, in both ways, result will be the number of `char`, so, the answer is definitly **NO**!

But I want to add something different to this answer.

When I decompile [`String.ToCharArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) method, it looks like:

```
public unsafe char[] ToCharArray()
{
  int length = this.Length;
  char[] chArray = new char[length];
  if (length > 0)
  {
    fixed (char* smem = &this.m_firstChar)
      fixed (char* dmem = chArray)
        string.wstrcpyPtrAligned(dmem, smem, length);
  }
  return chArray;
}
```

`ToCharArray` uses `unsafe` code that manipulates pointers, along with the private [`wstrcpyPtrAligned`](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/245849-System.String.wstrcpyPtrAligned%28Char%2a,Char%2a,Int32%29) method in the base class library. It is normally faster than doing the same thing in managed code, which has to check array bounds.

### But

It makes a complete pass over the string, so if you do not require that, **filling character arrays manually may be faster**.

Since `ToCharArray()` method returns a char array, which you can modify in-place. This sometimes improves the performance of code.

Comment: I don't think the mutability of the thing is in question, and, as you can see, the `ToCharArray` method checks the length of the string anyway, so there's certainly not going to be a performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

I don' think it will give different result in any scenario!

but if I use its overloaded method i.e. `ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)`
then obviously it can give different value of length property as you give the length.

Also I can not override this `ToCharArray()` method in my custom class like `ToString()` method. So If you want to calculate the length only, then using `myString.Length` makes more sense than using `myString.ToCharArray().Length`.

Comment: We can not override ToCharArray() method like ToString() method. I will overrride the ToString() method to add some extra logic in my class.